# Как использовать Интерфейс IComparable для сортировки List

Tags: c#, list

Есть реализация интерфейса IComparable. В базовом классе BaseCats. Стандартной реализации.

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        BaseCats bCats = obj as BaseCats;
        if (bCats != null)
        {
            if (this._Age < bCats._Age)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (this._Age > bCats._Age)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Параметр должен быть типа BaseCats");
        }
```

Так вот вопрос как его использовать если есть такой List

```
List<BaseCats> cats = new List<BaseCats>
        {
            new BaseCats("Ману", 5),
            new BaseCats("Марго", 10),
            new BaseCats("Васян", 7)
        };
```

И нужно сделать сортировку по возрасту? Возможно ли это вообще провернуть с List или нет? И если можно то как и если нельзя то почему?

Пробовал сортировать 
cats.Sort(cats); В уроке так было!
cats.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

доступа к свойству _Age из  Programs.cs нет! Свойство с модификатором protected.

Comment: Вы пробовали [сортировать](https://ideone.com/o5MBSx) этот список? Что получилось? В базовом классе это в `BaseCats`? Попробуйте создать [исполняемый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) чтобы не было лишних вопросов.

Comment: @default locale Спасибо! Огромное! Не разу не пользовался пробовал как в уроках не работало. Хотя нужно было просто (String.Join) использовать.

Comment: У вас же в `CompareTo()` нет какой-то логики помимо сравнения, тогда можно сортировать так: `cats.Sort((a, b) => a.Age.CompareTo(b.Age));`

Comment: @Jagailo Спасибо! Так тоже попробую! Хотя если сортировать это в файле Program.cs как мне нужно то такой способ не подойдёт. Так как у меня нет доступа к свойству _Age из файла Program.cs извиняюсь что информация в вопросе была не полной. Сейчас добавлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сортировки достаточно вызвать `Sort` без параметров:

```
cats.Sort();
```

[`List.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx) при вызове без аргументов использует компаратор по-умолчанию, который умеет определять, что тип списка (`BaseCats`) реализует `IComparable` и сортировать список используя `CompareTo`.

> This method uses the default comparer `Comparer<T>.Default` for type T to determine the order of list elements. The `Comparer<T>.Default` property checks whether type T implements the `IComparable<T>` generic interface and uses that implementation, if available. **If not, `Comparer<T>.Default` checks whether type T implements the `IComparable` interface.** If type T does not implement either interface, `Comparer<T>.Default` throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

В качестве аргумента для `Sort` можно передавать реализации `Comparison` и `IComparer`. Это может понадобится если объект не реализует интерфейсы сравнения, либо если требуется сортировать список разными способами. Посмотрите примеры в [документации по каждой перегрузке метода](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx).

Как выводится список неважно, `cats.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` должно сработать.

Comment: Да работает! Но мне нужно было сделать это с помощью IComparable вот и задал вопрос! Так как в проекте сразу стал использовать лист ,а не массив.