# Интерфейс IComparable<> и IComparable для реализации сортировки

Tags: c#, list, интерфейс

Уже об этом писал.
[Как использовать Интерфейс IComparable для сортировки List](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857957/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81-icomparable-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-list/857962#857962)

Думал понял. Для задачи на тот момент информации хватило. Но теперь немного нужно изменить. Уже долго вожусь не как не рожу!!! Нужна помощь.

Нужно сделать возможность сортировки по имени и по возрасту.
Есть список

Program.cs

```
// Созданные Коты 
        List<BaseCats> cats = new List<BaseCats>
        {
            new BaseCats("Ману", 5),
            new BaseCats("Марго", 10),
            new BaseCats("Васян", 7)
        };


        cats.Sort();
        cats.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

List и его вызов.

Доступа из файла Progam.cs к свойством _Name и _Age нет. 
Они с модификатором доступа protected.

Есть метод для выбора сортировки, Его реализация не полная 
на неё будет влиять ответы. Так как она зависит от `IComparable` и `IComparable<BaseCats>` возможно хватит и одного `IComparable` , но я пока только так придумал.

BaseCats.cs // базовый класс где реализуются интерфейс `IComparable` `IComparable<BaseCats>`

```
// Метод сотритрвки
    public void SortMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Вы хотити сортировать котов по: ");
        Console.WriteLine($"1) Имени: (нажмите 1): ");
        Console.WriteLine($"1) Возрасту: (нажмите 2): ");

        string enterSort = Console.ReadLine();

        var sortEnter;

        switch (enterSort)
        {
            case "1":
                CompareTo(_Name);
                break;

            case "2":
                CompareTo(_Age);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Вопрос?** как сделать реализацию сортировки с помощью `IComparable`
по имени и возрасту?

Делал реализации

`IComparable`

```
// Реализация IComparable
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            BaseCats bCats = obj as BaseCats;
            if (bCats != null)
            {
                if (this._Age < bCats._Age)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else if (this._Age > bCats._Age)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Параметр должен быть типа BaseCats");
            }
```

`IComparable<BaseCats>`

```
public int CompareTo(BaseCats other)
    {
        return other._Name.CompareTo(other._Name);
    }
```

Первая реализация работает при поиске по умолчанию. С вызовом о котором написано выше.

Реализацию с выбором вызывал так.

`BaseCats baseCats = new BaseCats();`

`baseCats.SortMethod();`

`cats.Sort();`

`cats.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В SOLID в рассказе про [Open Close Principle](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) очень часто приводят пример фильтрации по двум параметрам (трём и более: классы не изменяются).

Приведу пример кода из видеокурса Udemy - Design Patterns in C# and .NET глава 01 The SOLID Design Principles раздел 004 Open-Closed Principle:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Console;

namespace DotNetDesignPatternDemos.SOLID.OCP
{
  public enum Color
  {
    Red, Green, Blue
  }

  public enum Size
  {
    Small, Medium, Large, Huge
  }

  public class Product
  {
    public string Name;
    public Color Color;
    public Size Size;

    public Product(string name, Color color, Size size)
    {
      Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(name));
      Color = color;
      Size = size;
    }
  }

  public class ProductFilter
  {
    // let's suppose we don't want ad-hoc queries on products
    public IEnumerable<Product> FilterByColor(IEnumerable<Product> products, Color color)
    {
      foreach (var p in products)
        if (p.Color == color)
          yield return p;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Product> FilterBySize(IEnumerable<Product> products, Size size)
    {
      foreach (var p in products)
        if (p.Size == size)
          yield return p;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Product> FilterBySizeAndColor(IEnumerable<Product> products, Size size, Color color)
    {
      foreach (var p in products)
        if (p.Size == size && p.Color == color)
          yield return p;
    } // state space explosion
      // 3 criteria = 7 methods

    // OCP = open for extension but closed for modification
  }

  // we introduce two new interfaces that are open for extension

  public interface ISpecification<T>
  {
    bool IsSatisfied(Product p);
  }

  public interface IFilter<T>
  {
    IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> items, ISpecification<T> spec);
  }

  public class ColorSpecification : ISpecification<Product>
  {
    private Color color;

    public ColorSpecification(Color color)
    {
      this.color = color;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfied(Product p)
    {
      return p.Color == color;
    }
  }

  public class SizeSpecification : ISpecification<Product>
  {
    private Size size;

    public SizeSpecification(Size size)
    {
      this.size = size;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfied(Product p)
    {
      return p.Size == size;
    }
  }

  // combinator
  public class AndSpecification<T> : ISpecification<T>
  {
    private ISpecification<T> first, second;

    public AndSpecification(ISpecification<T> first, ISpecification<T> second)
    {
      this.first = first ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(first));
      this.second = second ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(second));
    }

    public bool IsSatisfied(Product p)
    {
      return first.IsSatisfied(p) && second.IsSatisfied(p);
    }
  }

  public class BetterFilter : IFilter<Product>
  {
    public IEnumerable<Product> Filter(IEnumerable<Product> items, ISpecification<Product> spec)
    {
      foreach (var i in items)
        if (spec.IsSatisfied(i))
          yield return i;
    }
  }

  public class Demo
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var apple = new Product("Apple", Color.Green, Size.Small);
      var tree = new Product("Tree", Color.Green, Size.Large);
      var house = new Product("House", Color.Blue, Size.Large);

      Product[] products = {apple, tree, house};

      var pf = new ProductFilter();
      WriteLine("Green products (old):");
      foreach (var p in pf.FilterByColor(products, Color.Green))
        WriteLine($" - {p.Name} is green");

      // ^^ BEFORE

      // vv AFTER
      var bf = new BetterFilter();
      WriteLine("Green products (new):");
      foreach (var p in bf.Filter(products, new ColorSpecification(Color.Green)))
        WriteLine($" - {p.Name} is green");

      WriteLine("Large products");
      foreach (var p in bf.Filter(products, new SizeSpecification(Size.Large)))
        WriteLine($" - {p.Name} is large");

      WriteLine("Large blue items");
      foreach (var p in bf.Filter(products,
        new AndSpecification<Product>(new ColorSpecification(Color.Blue), new SizeSpecification(Size.Large)))
      )
      {
        WriteLine($" - {p.Name} is big and blue");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

В видео всё это демонстрируется прямо по ходу рефакторнига, а в приведённом образце обратите внимание на код "до" и "код после".

Фильтрация и сортировка - несколько разные вещи, но в вашем случае одним простым `IComparable` не выкрутиться, так как у вас сразу несколько условий, а приведённый код как раз решает именно проблему множественности условий.

Отдельно обратите внимание, как повышается читаемость кода: у вас уйдут магические константы а появятся понятные enum'ы с ByName и другими параметрами сортировки, разве что при вводе понадобится привести цифру к enum.

Тут ещё в ответе должно быть про предназначение и разницу между `IComparable` и `IComparer` (вы использовали первый, а им задачу не решить - зато можно написать два IComparer - один для имени, один для возраста, возможно вам и достаточно этого было бы), поэтому я оставлю ссылку на вот такой вопрос:

- [Что лучше использовать IComparer или IComparable?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/812988/213987)

В ответе VladD есть готовый пример реализации именно на базе IComparer:

```
class SurnameComparer : IComparer<Human>
{
    public int Compare(Human p, Human q)
    {
        return p.Surname.CompareTo(q.Surname);
    }
}
```

Хотя я бы под вашу задачу наверное пошёл бы по пути написания двух linq-выражений.

Comment: @A K Очень интересный пример. Посмотрю уроки. Хотя для меня это код немного сложновато на первый взгляд для чтения, нужно разобраться. Про Enum я тоже думал но так как был ограничен во времени то разбираться не стал. Теперь время есть! Но мне нужно решить проблему именно с помощью `IComparable`! А, почему нельзя не могли бы поподробней объяснить.

Comment: @A K Спасибо! Сейчас почитаю.